# Android Action Bar : App Icon & Title

Tags: android, themes, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Is it possible to use fragment tabs on action bar with the Theme.Holo.NoActionBar theme?

I mean... I already use this theme on my layouts but apparently it is overriden since the fragments have to show up in the action bar?

What I wanted to achieve is to actually get rid of the Title and App Icon over the fragment tabs. Something similar to the Google Music app.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What I wanted to achieve is to actually get rid of the Title and App Icon over the fragment tabs. Something similar to the Google Music app.

Try calling `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)` and `setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)` on your `ActionBar`, and leave the theme alone.

Comment: Ignore my answer, I don't know why I wanted you to style stuff, use this answer. <3 commonsguy

Answer (score 0):

You can [style the action bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Style) based on your needs. I'm quite certain you can also remove the app icon and title from there. Using a NoActionbar theme by default and then recreating the action bar on your own kinda defeats the purpose of the action bar. I suggest you use a theme with action bar and then style the bar according to your needs. This [page](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html) has a decent implementation.